# string length difference between Java 6 and Java 7

Tags: java, string, oracle, encoding

I have a program which read files(using bufferedreader) row by row and writes its content to a table column size 4000 bytes in Oracle db.By the way in oracle there is a column length restriction of VARCHAR2 (4000 BYTE). My application was working fine in java6. However I come across a strange situation when I upgrade to java7. The error I get in during insertion in java7  is

```
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

This error occurs when you insert more than 4000 bytes in the column.
The file I am trying is big and every column size is 1850 chars(including nonascii chars), and also when I run this program with java7 everytime exception occurs in a different row.
My question is what difference between java6 and java7 can cause this string length difference which causes this ORA error.

Edit for clarification: I am not asking about ORA error, its already clear for me. My question is what difference between java6-java7 can cause this ? Because I can successfully insert with java6.

Edit2: Code is basically like this.

```
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            linenum++;
            prpst.setString(1, line);
            prpst.addBatch();

            if (++batchedLines == 200) {
                prpst.executeBatch();
                batchedLines = 0;
                prpst.clearBatch();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Actually you can specify column lengths of `VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was not asking why this error occurs, I ask what difference between java6-7 can cause different length calculation. Please read question again.

Comment: It also might help if you post the Java code which is causing the behavior.

Comment: Is your Java 6 and 7 testing in the same environment - same locale, character set, etc.? And to the same database (or at least same version, and same table definition)?

Comment: @AlexPoole exactly same. I just change the start script and this is the result. By the way I am using IBM JDK if its important.